# Guardar dataframe de python en una ruta especifica

Tags: python, base-de-datos, pandas, dataframe, guardar

Hola tengo un dataframe que estoy generando a partir de listas, y necesito que se guarde en una ruta especifica en un disco duro externo, alguna idea?

Comment: qué tal: `MiDF.to_csv("F:\\miarchivo.csv", sep=',', index=False, encoding='utf-8')`?

Comment: Hola Silvia, bienvenida a [es.so]. Te recomiendo mirarte [tour] y [ask] para conocer un poco mejor el sitio, como realizar buenas preguntas y de paso ganar tu primera medalla ;). No especificas como intentas o quieres guardar el DF ¿texto plano (to_csv, to_json), pickle (to_pickle), xlsx (to_exel), etc? ¿otros formatos externos como Feather o HDF5? ¿has intentado algo? ¿te genera algún error concreto? Por norma general basta con especificar la ruta absoluta a la unidad externa de destino que quieras, tal  como comenta jachguate, o bien cambiar el directorio de trabajo del proceso a ella antes.